# Python: Is there a way to access variables from other functions without using 'global'?

Tags: python, scope

Here's an example on what I'm thinking:

```
def check_args():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.exit('Reason')
    if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
        sys.exit('ERROR: Folder %s was not found!' % sys.argv[1])
    global path
    path = sys.argv[1]
```

As you can tell after check_args() completes succefully the "path" variable has universal meaning - you can use it in other functions as de-facto variable.

So I'm thinking if there is a way to access "path" e.g. check_args.path?

How about in python v3?

Comment: This might just be an example, but if this is close to your actual code, you might want to look into a commandline parsing library (`argparse` is the most recent one to be included with python).

Comment: You don't have to put the code into a function. Just define a global `path` variable by defining it somewhere near the top of your module. You _can_ store it as an attribute of a function as in @lanzz's answer, but that's almost the same thing since your function is a global module object.

Comment: Is there a good reason for check_args not to simply return the value, and let the caller worry about where it is saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python functions are objects. You can define whatever custom properties you want on them:

```
def a():
    a.test = 123

a()
a.test # => 123
```

Comment: Needing attributes on functions is usually a sign of you wanting a class, possibly with `__call__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the value

```
def check_args():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.exit('Reason')
    if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
        sys.exit('ERROR: Folder %s was not found!' % sys.argv[1])
    path = sys.argv[1]
    return path

my_path = check_args()
```

or when using `if __name__ ...`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_path = check_args()
    results = do_something(path)
```